# R: Separate string based on set of regular expressions

Tags: r, string, dataframe, match

I have a data frame `foo.df` that contains one variable that is just a very long string consisting of several substrings. Additionally, I have vectors of characters that match parts of the string. Example for the variable in the data frame:

`foo.df$var[1]
[1] "Peter Paul SmithLabour3984234.55%Hans NicholsConservative103394.13%Turnout294834.3%`

Now an example for the vectors of characters:

`head(candidates)
[1] "Peter Paul Smith"  "Hans Nichols" "Denny Gross"            "Walter Mittens"

[5] "Charles Butt"    "Mitch Esterhazy"`

I want to create a variable `foo.df$candidate1` that contains the name of the first candidate appearing in the string (i.e. `food.df$candidate1[1]` would be `Peter Paul Smith`). I was trying to approach this with `grepl` but it doesn't work as `grepl` only uses the first the first entry from `candidates`. Any idea how this could be done efficiently?

Comment: `gregexpr("%","Peter Paul SmithLabour3984234.55%Hans NicholsConservative103394.13%Turnout294834.3%")` returns every location that a `%` occurs. You can use this with base R to extract what you want. Alternatively, the `stringr` package has premade functions to handle string subsetting, extracting, replacing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex OR character, `|`, with `paste` and `regmatches/regexpr`.

```
candidates <- scan(what = character(), text = '
"Peter Paul Smith"  "Hans Nichols" "Denny Gross" "Walter Mittens"')

var1 <- "Peter Paul SmithLabour3984234.55%Hans NicholsConservative103394.13%Turnout294834.3%"

foo.df <- data.frame(var1)

pat <- paste(candidates, collapse = "|")
regmatches(foo.df$var1, regexpr(pat, foo.df$var1))
#[1] "Peter Paul Smith"

foo.df$candidate1 <- regmatches(foo.df$var1, regexpr(pat, foo.df$var1))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very elegant!